# Python: Parse a line and exclude last token

Tags: python, parsing, tokenize

I've a really simple question regarding line parsing in Python.

I've a file containing lines like these:

```
MV0346FDG-PFHTGE-CFSGD-22205-C0

MV0346FDG-PFHTGE-CFSGD-22205-34354-FHHTRW-0

MV0346FDG-PFHTGE-CFSGD-DTRHG-22205-AA1
```

I need to save to a new file these lines excluding characters after last "-".

The result shall be the following:

```
MV0346FDG-PFHTGE-CFSGD-22205

MV0346FDG-PFHTGE-CFSGD-22205-34354-FHHTRW

MV0346FDG-PFHTGE-CFSGD-DTRHG-22205
```

How can I code this?

Comment: Check out open, write, and split and you'll be golden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply [find the last instance](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=rfind#string.rfind) of '-' and slice it off

```
q = 'MV0346FDG-PFHTGE-CFSGD-22205-C0'
q[:q.rfind('-')]
'MV0346FDG-PFHTGE-CFSGD-22205'
```

See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) for info on file read/write

Comment: Why make it harder on yourself? `rpartition` or `rsplit` are simpler, and have no way to accidentally write an off-by-one error, and `rpartition` even makes it impossible to read past the end when given an unexpected empty line.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `rsplit()`:

```
for line in infile:
    token, _ = line.rsplit('-', 1)
    outfile.write(token + '\n')
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!It worked flawlessly!!

Answer (score 0):

Python strings have nice methods for splitting into smaller strings, so there's no need to go searching for characters and slicing them. You can see all of those methods [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods), or just type `help(str)` in your interactive terminal.

So:

```
with open(inpath) as infile, open(outpath, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        main, hyphen, last = line.rpartition('-')
        outfile.write(main + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rfind` also

```
for line in file:
    outfile.write(line[:line.rfind('-')] + "\n")
```